# Interacting With Dynamic Data Table And Scraping Oil Data From Website in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to pull refinery data and was wondering if anyone had any ideas for how to use Selenium or the requests library in Python to input a start and end date, submit the query, and scrape the resulting data from this website https://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us? From the link, you click on SONRIS Data Portal --> Click Production Audit dropdown --> Then click the R3 (Refinery) Activity Report Product Listing IDR Icon (looks like a table). You then execute a query given a beginning and end date. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. I don't see any HTTP headers I can use, and am not sure how to use the Selenium library to navigate the website. Thanks!

Comment: Based on some of the URLs it's accessing, this looks like an [Oracle APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) based web app. That plus the Captcha they serve might make that tricky.

Comment: I notice that page has an option to get a "lite" version of the report, at the URL https://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/Cart_Con_R3ACTIVRPT1 That looks like it has the same information, and is way easier to scrape.

Comment: @NickODell Thank you. I might end up doing that for the R3 refinery data, but was also looking at R2 Oil Transporter data which uses one of those interactive tables only. I was hoping it could be automated somehow but looks like itll have to be manual. Thank you for your insights